# already had "do" but still have error "loop without do", excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to create a userform to input data for each sales order, one order can consist of many products so I wrote as below. I added "do ... loop" to add another product in an SO but I've got "loop without do" error. 
Thanks if you can help me to find out the solution for this error or can show me better way to do this task.
Thank you.

```
Private Sub button_OK_Click()
Dim nbr As Integer
Dim SOno As Integer
Dim choice As Integer
SOno = Sheets("engine").Range("B2")
Do
    nbr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("SO").Range("c4:C50")) + 1 'no. of rows
    Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 0) = nbr
    Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 1) = "SO" & WorksheetFunction.Text(SOno, "00000")
    Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 2) = cus_name
    Sheets("so").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 3) = prd_name
    Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 6) = qty
choice = MsgBox("Do you want to add new product for current SO?", vbYesNo)
If choice = vbYes Then
Loop
Else
Unload input_SO_UF
End If
Sheets("engine").Range("B2") = SOno + 1 'max SO no
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot interleave loops and if then structure. Replace your `If Choice ... Loop ... End If ` by a correct end of loop test like for example `Loop Until choice <> vbYes`

Comment: Have your entire loopinside the If before the Else.

Comment: Could you do something along these lines `If choice <> vbYes Then exit do:Unload input_SO_UF:end if`

Comment: thanks Vincent G, it works :)

Comment: yes QHarr, I intended to have the entire if choice = vbyes

Comment: Nathan_Sav: I tried exit do but it's not working. "do without loop" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub button_OK_Click()
    Dim nbr As Integer
    Dim SOno As Integer
    SOno = Sheets("engine").Range("B2")
    Do
        nbr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("SO").Range("c4:C50")) + 1 'no. of rows
        Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 0) = nbr
        Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 1) = "SO" & WorksheetFunction.Text(SOno, "00000")
        Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 2) = cus_name
        Sheets("so").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 3) = prd_name
        Sheets("SO").Range("r_cell").Offset(nbr, 6) = qty
    Loop While vbYes = MsgBox("Do you want to add new product for current SO?", vbYesNo)

    Unload input_SO_UF
    Sheets("engine").Range("B2") = SOno + 1 'max SO no
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Vincent. It's makes my code shorter and also learn more about loop until and loop while :)